# AVL-tree clearing

Tags: c++, algorithm, avl-tree

I don't know, why _clear don't remove elements from a tree. Probably, needs to override destructor.

```
class Node {
    T _val;
    Node *_left;
    Node *_right;
    int _height;

    explicit Node(T _val = T()) : _val(_val), _left(nullptr), _right(nullptr), _height(1) {};

    friend class AVL_Tree<T>;
};

void AVL_Tree<T>::_clear(Node<T>*vertex) {
    if(vertex != nullptr) {
        _clear(vertex->_left);
        _clear(vertex->_right);
        delete vertex;
    }
    vertex = nullptr;
}
```

There are stay NULL linked nodes, why they don't delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
AVL_Tree<T>::_clear(Node<T>*vertex)
```

You passed a pointer to `Node` by value, but you want to change the pointer and have the change propagate out of the function. The C++ way to do this is pass a *reference* to the pointer-to-`Node`:

```
AVL_Tree<T>::_clear(Node<T>*&vertex)
```

PS. Don't begin an identifier with an underscore.  That's reserved for library implementers. So:

```
AVL_Tree<T>::clear(Node<T>*&vertex)
```